# How to display specific date format on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, nunjucks

How can I go about formatting a date displayed to the user on a website?  Basically, I am grabbing the date from a MySQL table and displaying on the website using Nunjucks.

MySQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `awards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `awardtime` TIME,
  `awardate` DATE,
```

HTML Code to display the date and time:

```
{{ results.awardtime }}
{{ results.awardate }}
```

Output: 
Wed Nov 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

Desired Output (Example):
11-20-2019

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateStr = 'Wed Nov 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)'; // results.awardate

var date = new Date(dateStr);
var y = date.getFullYear();
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var d = date.getDate();

var nice = m + "-" + d + "-" + y;

// {{ nice }}
console.log( nice ); // 11-27-2019
```

Comment: While your code may answer the PO's question, you should add a brief explanation of what you have done and how that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this its working as per your requirement

```
let date = new Date(results.awardtime);

let year = date.getFullYear();
let month = date.getMonth() +1
let day = date.getDate();
let finaldate = `${month}-${day}-${year}`

{finaldate}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format it without adding dependencies:

```
const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(date).replace(/\//g, '-')
```

**OR** With [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/):

```
import { format } from `date-fns`;

const formattedDate = format(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

**OR** you can try: https://github.com/techmsi/nunjucks-date

Answer (score 0):

The big issue with date is date format depends by country (locale). Moreover the result can have some variants e.g. use `-`, `/` or `.` as delimeter. Also don't forget about timezones, ha.

At this time your render implies `{{ results.awardtime.toString() }}`. I recommend to implement a [custom filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-filters) to date render.

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addFilter('date', function (datetime) {
  // Here you can use any function from other answers
  return new Date(+datetime).toLocaleDateString('es-CL', {
    year: 'numeric', 
    day: '2-digit', 
    month: '2-digit'
  });
};

var html = env.renderString(`Today: {{ now | date }}`, {now: Date.now()});
console.log(html);
```